# Can I use single conftest.py for different test directories?

Tags: pytest

Here is my test directory:

```
test/
    unit/
        some test files 
        conftest.py
    acceptance/
        some test files
        conftest.py
```

Right now there are two conftest files for fixtures. Can I combine them into one `conftest.py` file? If yes, where should I keep that common `conftest.py`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can combine the fixtures into a `conftest.py` file within the top-level `test` directory. Per [this documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#conftest-py-local-per-directory-plugins), conftest files are per directory. The conftest file (and fixtures and plugins therein) should be available to test files in that directory and in child directories. If you do that, I recommend making your `test` directory into a python package by adding a `__init__.py` file (per [the note in this documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#conftest-py-local-per-directory-plugins)).